# az aks create - it used to create Service Principal now Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure, kubernetes, service-principal

Update:
A colleague who works for Microsoft said:

> Changelog entry for this behaviour change is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/release-notes-azure-cli.md#aks-3

---

I'm following the proper instructions and the documentation must be out of date.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal

> **Automatically create and use a service principal.**
> When you create an AKS cluster in the Azure portal or using the az aks create command, Azure can automatically generate a service principal.
> In the following Azure CLI example, a service principal is not specified. In this scenario, the Azure CLI creates a service principal for the AKS cluster. To successfully complete the operation, your Azure account must have the proper rights to create a service principal.

```
az aks create --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup
```

This is what happened a few months ago - see **Finished service principal creation**:

[image]

Now when I try I get **Add role propagation**:

[image]

The problem is querying the servicePrincipalProfile.clientId results in **msi**, I need the guid of the service principal not the Managed Service Identity.

```
$CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)
echo $CLIENT_ID
```

Used to work:

[image]

Now its changed:

[image]

How do I create the Kubernetes Cluster with a Service Principal as the documentation states and how it used to work?

Repro steps:

https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/AzureTraining/blob/master/Hands-On-Labs-That-Work/80-Kubernetes.md

https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/AzureTraining/blob/master/Hands-On-Labs-That-Work/85-Kubernetes-Deployment.md

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Comment: @JeyJ I made it work using the `kubeletidentity` see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Reference: I got the same and following your [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/release-notes-azure-cli.md#aks-3) I found that this worked.

```
az aks show -g aks -n cluster --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.clientId -o tsv
```

[image]

and this returned the appropriate guide, that I could use for my RBAC assignment

```
# get the clientId of the cluster
$clientId = (az aks show -g aks -n cluster --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.clientId -o tsv)

# get the resourceId of the registry
$acrId=(az acr show -g acr -n myacr --query id -o tsv)


# give authority for cluster id to the acr pull
az role assignment create $clientId --role AcrPull --scope $acrId
```

Comment: what is -g aks in it ?? is it resource group?

Comment: @AhsamAslam yes that's right.